# Java Index Out Of Bounds Exception When Loading Tile Map

Tags: java, save, loading, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

In the tool I am making to aid me in creating my new game I need to be able to load and save tile maps and edit them. When I click the mouse it will change the current tile the mouse is hovering over to the tile of my choice. For some reason whenever I click on any tile the first tile is always changed to some strange blackish color and an index out of bounds exception is thrown. It says **"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Engine.Map.loadUpdatedMap(Map.java:161)
    at Engine.Pane.mousePressed(Pane.java:65)**. I checked the text file and it is replaced with the current tile size (when it should be 0). Code is posted below, any ideas?

## this is where the error occurs (Map.java)

```
public void loadUpdatedMap(){
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName + ".txt")));

            for (int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++){
                String read = reader.readLine();
                String[] skips = read.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < mapWidth; j++){
                    map[i][j] = Byte.parseByte(skips[j]);
                }
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

## This is the way I am replacing the tiles (Pane.java)

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (map.created && map.tileSize != 0){
        currentX = e.getX() / map.tileSize;
        if (e.getY() / map.tileSize > 1){
            currentY = (e.getY() - map.tileSize) / map.tileSize;
        }
        else{
            currentY = (e.getY() / map.tileSize);
        }
        map.setTile(currentX, currentY, currentSelection);
        map.loadUpdatedMap();
    }
}
```

## Code used to save map

```
public void saveToLocation(){
    try{
        if (fileName == null){
            fileName = "default";
        }
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), fileName + ".txt"));
        System.out.println("File was saved to: " + new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), fileName + ".txt"));
        fout.write(String.valueOf(tileSize).getBytes());
        fout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        fout.write(String.valueOf(mapWidth).getBytes());
        fout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        fout.write(String.valueOf(mapHeight).getBytes());
        fout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                fout.write(String.valueOf(map[i][j]).getBytes());
                fout.write(String.valueOf(" ").getBytes());
            }
            fout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        }
        fout.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

## Before anything is clicked

[image: Before Clicks]

## After first click

[image: After Click]

## The text file results

[image: After Click]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you debugged the code line-by-line to see where the value is changed from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your `ships` array after

```
 String[] skips = read.split(" ");
```

According to your code it is `mapWidth` and then you are trying to extract that many elements from the array.

Maybe

```
for (int j = 0; j < skips.length; j++){
```

would be more correct